# Embed PDF Byte Data in HTML

Tags: javascript, pdf, servlets, arrays

This should be working, but it seems I am missing something.

I have a pdf file on a local drive. Obviously Chrome and other browsers can't get that local URL since it's sandboxed, so I have a servlet pulling the data from the local drive and sending it back through an ajax call to the web client. I'm not getting any errors, and it seems a pdf viewer is loading, but the file itself won't display. I am encoding it ahead of time, but it still won't work. I will display my numerous approaches below, but I won't include the servlet code since that seems to be working.

**Attempt 1:**

```
function embedFile(){
    $.get("FileGetter", function(pdfText){

        var base64EncodedPDF = b64EncodeUnicode(pdfText);
        $("#embedHolder").append("<object id='embedder' width='80%' height='600px'><embed width=100% height=100%"
                                     + ' type="application/pdf"'
                                     + ' src="data:application/pdf;base64,'
                                     + base64EncodedPDF
                                     + "></embed></object>");

            });
        }

 function b64EncodeUnicode(str) {
     return btoa(encodeURIComponent(str).replace(/%([0-9A-F]{2})/g, function(match, p1) {
                return String.fromCharCode('0x' + p1);
            }));
        }
```

**Attempt 2:**

```
function embedFile(){
    $.get("FileGetter", function(pdfText){

        var base64EncodedPDF = b64EncodeUnicode(pdfText);
        var obj = $('<object id="repObjID" type="application/pdf" width="100%" height="600" border="2"></object>'); 
        obj.attr('data',base64EncodedPDF); 
        var embed = $('<embed type="application/pdf"></embed>'); 
        embed.attr('src',base64EncodedPDF); 
        $('#repObjID').append(embed); 
        $("#docHolder").html(obj);
    }

function b64EncodeUnicode(str) {
    return btoa(encodeURIComponent(str).replace(/%([0-9A-F]{2})/g,               function(match, p1) {
                return String.fromCharCode('0x' + p1);
            }));
}
```

Comment: 1) Are you sure your PDF viewer does accept base64 data encoded in the src URL? 2) How does the server get the the data from local drive? I suggest the user has to choose the file, which is then uploaded (via AJAX?) to the servlet?

Comment: Not quite. The user is selecting a record in the database and on that record is a URL that points to a local directory. The server then reads the data from the local URL and converts it to bytes, which are then transferred to the client via the response. I *thought* it was working, but I was able to open the document in a new window semi-successfully. The pdf shows up, and is the correct number of pages, yet each page is completely blank. As for the PDF viewer, I'm using the chrome default.

Comment: You could make a binary [Blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob) (with content type), and then create an [object URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL), and load that in an iframe.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Download the binary data with ajax, into an arraybuffer

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;
xhr.open('get', '/path/to/pdf', true);
xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
xhr.send();
```

2. Create Blob and Object URL

```
var blob = new Blob([xhr.response], {type: 'application/pdf'});
var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
```

3. Load URL in iframe

```
iframe.src = url;
```

Demo: https://webblocks.nl/tests/ajax-pdf.html

Comment: This is nod "embedding data". The data are still on the web server as you need to GET it!

Comment: that works, thanks! and if someone needs to use base64 as source, just google `base64 to blob js` and follow steps 2 and 3

Comment: you can set responseType to `blob`.