# How to show pdf in browser using byte array of pdf in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a controller which send the response Entity as response to ajax call which is in byte array form of pdf.
Now i want to show that in browser but nothing works. i tried every suggentions from old stackoverlow questions but nothing works.

here is my response from spring controller

```
     `  %PDF-1.4
       %����
       6 0 obj
  <</Filter/FlateDecode/Length 1983>>stream
  x�� .......... [snip rest of the output]`
```

here is my ajax code

```
 $(".form").submit(function(e) {
                    var form = $(this);
                    var url = _contextPath + "pdf/" + id;
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "GET",
                        url: url,
                        data: form.serialize(),
                        datatype: "application/pdf",
                        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
                        {
                            console.log(data);
                            let pdfWindow = window.open("");
                            var bb = btoa(encodeURIComponent((data.replace(/[\u00A0-\u2666]/g, function(c) {
                                return '&#' + c.charCodeAt(0) + ';';
                            }))));
                            console.log(bb);
                            var file = new Blob([bb], {type:'application/pdf'});
                            console.log(file);
                            var fileUrl = URL.createObjectURL(file);
                            pdfWindow.document.write("<iframe width='100%' height='100%' src= '"+file+"'></iframe>");
                            /*var pdfData = btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(data)));
                            console.log(pdfData);
                            var pdfDataa = atob(pdfData);
                            console.log(pdfDataa);*/
                           /* var bb = btoa(encodeURIComponent((data.replace(/[\u00A0-\u2666]/g, function(c) {
                                return '&#' + c.charCodeAt(0) + ';';
                            }))));
                            console.log(bb);
                            var file = new Blob([bb], {type:'application/pdf'});
                            var fileUrl = URL.createObjectURL(file);
                            window.open(fileUrl,'', 'height=650,width=840');*/
                            //console.log(data);
                        //    window.open("data:application/pdf;base64, " + data, '', 'height=650,width=840');
                            /*var blob = new Blob( [data], { type: "application/pdf" });
                            var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                            var win = window.open();
                            win.document.write('<iframe src="' + fileURL + '" frameborder="0"' +
                                ' style="border:0; top:0px; left:0px; bottom:0px;' +
                                ' right:0px; width:100%; height:100%;" allowfullscreen></iframe>')*/
                           /* var datauri = 'data:application/pdf;base64,' + Base64.encode(data);
                            var win = window.open();
                            win.document.write('<iframe src="' + datauri + '" frameborder="0"' +
                                ' style="border:0; top:0px; left:0px; bottom:0px;' +
                                ' right:0px; width:100%; height:100%;" allowfullscreen></iframe>');*/
                            //var base64EncodedStr = btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(data)));
                            //window.open(data,"_blank","scrollbars=yes,resizable=yes");
                            //window.open("data:application/pdf," + encodeURI(data));
                           // window.open("data:application/pdf," + escape(data));
                            //window.open("data:application/pdf," + base64EncodedStr);
                          //  window.open("data:application/octet-stream;charset=utf-16le;base64,"+base64EncodedStr);

                          //  let pdfWindow = window.open("")
                           //   pdfWindow.document.write("<iframe width='100%' height='100%' src='data:application/pdf;base64, "
                           //     + blob+"'></iframe>");
                          /*  const byteArray = data;
                            const blob = new Blob([byteArray], {type: 'application/pdf'});
                            const blobURL = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                            var win = window.open();
                            win.document.write('<iframe src="' + blobURL + '" frameborder="0"' +
                                ' style="border:0; top:0px; left:0px; bottom:0px;' +
                                ' right:0px; width:100%; height:100%;" allowfullscreen></iframe>');*/
                           /* var len = data.length;
                            var buffer = new ArrayBuffer(len);
                            var view = new Uint8Array(buffer);
                            for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                                view[i] = binary.charCodeAt(i);
                            }
                            */
                            /*var base64EncodedStr = btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(data.toString())));
                            var pdfData = base64EncodedStr;

                            var x = window.open();
                            var iframe = x.document.createElement('iframe')
                            iframe.width = '100%'
                            iframe.height = '100%'
                            iframe.frameBorder = 0
                            iframe.style = "border: 0"
                            iframe.src = "data:application/pdf;base64, " + pdfData
                            x.document.body.appendChild(iframe);*/
                           // $('.form').unbind('submit').submit();

                        }
                    });
                    e.preventDefault();
                });
```

i tried every thing but i did not work

Comment: It's a GET request? Then in the document `<iframe id="frame"></iframe>`. Then in your js `var url = _contextPath + "pdf/" + id; frame.src = url;`. Or even simpler `<iframe url="#the_url#"></iframe>` if the url is static.

Comment: form data send from ajax call so i can not directly call the url. theresponse i get is in byte array so i want to show that in browser

Comment: Why `type` is set to `"GET"` then? Well anyway, the easiest would be to directly fetch your resource as Blob (this means overriding jQuery's XHR object's `responseType`, then you'd just have to set an iframe's src to `URL.createObjectURL(XHR.response);`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Found the solution here it is, i was sending byte array from spring controller which is in the form like **%PDF-1 %����**.
So i send base64 encoded string from spring controller and send the base64 encoded string to browser and it works.

**javascript code :**

```
var arrrayBuffer = base64ToArrayBuffer(data); //data is the base64 encoded string
function base64ToArrayBuffer(base64) {
    var binaryString = window.atob(base64);
    var binaryLen = binaryString.length;
    var bytes = new Uint8Array(binaryLen);
    for (var i = 0; i < binaryLen; i++) {
        var ascii = binaryString.charCodeAt(i);
        bytes[i] = ascii;
    }
    return bytes;
}
var blob = new Blob([arrrayBuffer], {type: "application/pdf"});
var link = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
window.open(link,'', 'height=650,width=840');
```

**convert byte array to base64 encoded string in spring controller**

```
String encodedString = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(bytearrayofpdf);
```

Comment: if we don't have access to the server, how do we convert the binary string / byte array to a base64 encoded string in javascript?

Comment: You can just download pdf as arraybuffer or even blob https://stackoverflow.com/a/48086247/4854931

Answer (score 3):

You can use [pdfObject](https://pdfobject.com/) to view pdfs in your browser. Just create a div with some id and insert the byte array that you get into that div.

```
   PDFObject.embed(<byte array>, "#pdfObjectViewer");
```

You need to download the pdfObject script and include it in your project from their site for this to work. or you can use this [CDN](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/pdfobject/).

Comment: minor note, its not just `<byte array>`, you need `data:application/pdf;base64,<byte array>` as the first parameter

Answer (score 0):

$ajax({type:get,xhr:function(){var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()if(xhr.readyState ==2){ if(xhr.status ==200){ xhr.responseType =".blob"} else{ xhr.responseType="text" } } } return xhr }, success:function(data){ Cost blob = new Blob([data],     {type:"application/pdf"})
cost url=window.URL.createObjectURL(blob) window.open(url)}})

Comment: Hi, your answer is unreadable. Please format your code: [formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). After doing it, we can see if your code addresses the question or not. Thank you.